# Does Hadoop delegation for WebHDFS REST API has dependency with Kerberos SPNEGO?

Tags: kerberos, hadoop2, webhdfs

According to documentataion for **WebHDFS REST API**

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#Delegation_Token_Operations

It is mentioned when security is on there is 2 mechanism

**Authentication using Kerberos SPNEGO when security is on**

**Authentication using Hadoop delegation token when security is on**

If i choose to use second option i.e **Authentication using Hadoop delegation token when security is on**

**Does it mean it can run without Kerberos configuration in hadoop setup?**

**Do i have to setup Kerberos in my hadoop configuration in this case ?**

Answer (score 3):

To put things in context: typically, you use SPNEGO when you **start your HTTP session**, then cache your credentials somehow to avoid the complex rounds of 3-way communication between client, server, and Kerberos KDC.

AFAIK, all the Hadoop UIs and REST APIs use a signed cookie after the initial SPNEGO, and it's completely transparent for you -- with the exception of WebHDFS.

Now, with WebHDFS, you have to manage your "credentials cache" explicitly:

1. start your session with a GET `?op=GETDELEGATIONTOKEN` -- you don't present any credentials, therefore it will trigger a SPNEGO authentication, then generate a Hadoop delegation token server-side
2. retrieve that delegation token from the JSON result
3. use that token to present your session credentials *explicitly* in the following GET / POST / PUT, by appending `&delegation=XXXXXX` to all URLs

Bottom line: yes, you have to set up your Kerberos configuration on client side. The delegation token only allows you to minimize the authentication overhead.